# Restoring Time Machine backups of HFS+ partitions to APFS volumes

Tags: macos, hard-drive, time-machine, partition

I have an external drive with two HFS+ partitions, each containing data. Both partitions are fully backed up with Time Machine.

I would like to convert the disk to APFS with two volumes, corresponding in name but differing in size to the HFS+ partitions. The APFS volumes will each be large enough to store the data currently on the corresponding HFS+ partitions.

After reformatting the disk and creating the new volumes, how can I restore the backed up data from the HFS+ partitions to the APFS volumes? Is it as simple as navigating to the new volumes in the Finder and entering Time Machine to restore the files?

*In case it's relevant, I'm planning to do this on an M1 MacBook Air running macOS Ventura 13.0 . And if this isn't possible, I do have the option of uploading the data to cloud storage and restoring it from there.*

Comment: Do it in Finder. Just drag and drop folders from TM disks to new APFS volumes.

Comment: Thanks @Gilby. I didn't expect it to be that easy as I was worried that simply copying the most recent backup over manually wouldn't work due to the incremental nature of Time Machine backups.

Comment: That is the magic of hard links (on HFS+ TM disk) and snapshots (on APFS TM disk). Whilst data is incrementally backed up, the file/folder structure of each backup is complete. Just double check your backups are complete. And accept the risk of your TM disk failing before you have time to recover to the new APFS volumes (unlikely, but serious if it happens). I would be more comfortable with duplicate TM backups on another disk.

Comment: Dragging from one disk to another makes a copy.  So if the source disk fails during the copy, both are screwed.  But if not, both are good.

Comment: Well yeah, if the source fails then you can't complete the copy - doesn't matter how you do it